# segmentation fault in c program with a trie

Tags: c, dictionary

I'm getting a seg fault with this spell check program. I tried gnu and valgrind but i can't figure out what is going on. (node is defined in a .h file)
the program is a spell check for cs50x 
it initially worked on the smaller dictionary but now it seg faults while running that as well.

here is the node:

```
typedef struct node    
{        
    bool is_word;
    struct node* letters[27];
}
node;
```

and here is the speller.c from the course - written by the course staff:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#include "dictionary.h"
#undef calculate
#undef getrusage

// default dictionary
#define DICTIONARY "dictionaries/large"

// prototype
double calculate(const struct rusage* b, const struct rusage* a);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // check for correct number of args
    if (argc != 2 && argc != 3)
    {
        printf("Usage: speller [dictionary] text\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // structs for timing data
    struct rusage before, after;

    // benchmarks
    double time_load = 0.0, time_check = 0.0, time_size = 0.0, time_unload = 0.0;

    // determine dictionary to use
    char* dictionary = (argc == 3) ? argv[1] : DICTIONARY;

    // load dictionary
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &before);
    bool loaded = load(dictionary);
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &after);

    // abort if dictionary not loaded
    if (!loaded)
    {
        printf("Could not load %s.\n", dictionary);
        return 1;
    }

    // calculate time to load dictionary
    time_load = calculate(&before, &after);

    // try to open text
    char* text = (argc == 3) ? argv[2] : argv[1];
    FILE* fp = fopen(text, "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open %s.\n", text);
        unload();
        return 1;
    }

    // prepare to report misspellings
    printf("\nMISSPELLED WORDS\n\n");

    // prepare to spell-check
    int index = 0, misspellings = 0, words = 0;
    char word[LENGTH+1];

    // spell-check each word in text
    for (int c = fgetc(fp); c != EOF; c = fgetc(fp))
    {
        // allow only alphabetical characters and apostrophes
        if (isalpha(c) || (c == '\'' && index > 0))
        {
            // append character to word
            word[index] = c;
            index++;

            // ignore alphabetical strings too long to be words
            if (index > LENGTH)
            {
                // consume remainder of alphabetical string
                while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF && isalpha(c));

                // prepare for new word
                index = 0;
            }
        }

        // ignore words with numbers (like MS Word can)
        else if (isdigit(c))
        {
            // consume remainder of alphanumeric string
            while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF && isalnum(c));

            // prepare for new word
            index = 0;
        }

        // we must have found a whole word
        else if (index > 0)
        {
            // terminate current word
            word[index] = '\0';

            // update counter
            words++;

            // check word's spelling
            getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &before);
            bool misspelled = !check(word);
            getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &after);

            // update benchmark
            time_check += calculate(&before, &after);

            // print word if misspelled
            if (misspelled)
            {
                printf("%s\n", word);
                misspellings++;
            }

            // prepare for next word
            index = 0;
        }
    }

    // check whether there was an error
    if (ferror(fp))
    {
        fclose(fp);
        printf("Error reading %s.\n", text);
        unload();
        return 1;
    }

    // close text
    fclose(fp);

    // determine dictionary's size
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &before);
    unsigned int n = size();
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &after);

    // calculate time to determine dictionary's size
    time_size = calculate(&before, &after);

    // unload dictionary
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &before);
    bool unloaded = unload();
    getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &after);

    // abort if dictionary not unloaded
    if (!unloaded)
    {
        printf("Could not unload %s.\n", dictionary);
        return 1;
    }

    // calculate time to unload dictionary
    time_unload = calculate(&before, &after);

    // report benchmarks
    printf("\nWORDS MISSPELLED:     %d\n", misspellings);
    printf("WORDS IN DICTIONARY:  %d\n", n);
    printf("WORDS IN TEXT:        %d\n", words);
    printf("TIME IN load:         %.2f\n", time_load);
    printf("TIME IN check:        %.2f\n", time_check);
    printf("TIME IN size:         %.2f\n", time_size);
    printf("TIME IN unload:       %.2f\n", time_unload);
    printf("TIME IN TOTAL:        %.2f\n\n", 
     time_load + time_check + time_size + time_unload);

    // that's all folks
    return 0;
}

/**
 * Returns number of seconds between b and a.
 */
double calculate(const struct rusage* b, const struct rusage* a)
{
    if (b == NULL || a == NULL)
    {
        return 0.0;
    }
    else
    {
        return ((((a->ru_utime.tv_sec * 1000000 + a->ru_utime.tv_usec) -
                 (b->ru_utime.tv_sec * 1000000 + b->ru_utime.tv_usec)) +
                ((a->ru_stime.tv_sec * 1000000 + a->ru_stime.tv_usec) -
                 (b->ru_stime.tv_sec * 1000000 + b->ru_stime.tv_usec)))
                / 1000000.0);
    }
}

// prototype of build trie function and unload
   int build_trie(int letter, node* root, FILE* dict);
   bool unloader(node* head);

// declare global variables
   node* root; 
   int total_words = 0; 

/**
 * Returns true if word is in dictionary else false.
 */
bool check(const char* word)
{
// iniitialize pointer trav to point to same as root
node* trav = root;

// iterate over the word to see if letters are "open" paths in trie  
int i = 0;
while (word[i] != '\0')
{
    // check if letter 
    if (isalpha(word[i]))
    {
        if (trav->letters[tolower(word[i]) -97] == NULL)  
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            trav = trav->letters[tolower(word[i]) -97];
            i++;
        }
    }
    else if (word[i] == '\'')
    {
        if (trav->letters[26] == NULL)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            trav = trav->letters[26];
            i++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

// at the end check if word
if (word[i] == '\0')
    return (trav->is_word);
else
    return false;
}

/**
 * Loads dictionary into memory.  Returns true if successful else false.
 */
bool load(const char* dictionary)
{
    // open a file to read the dictionary
    FILE* dict = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (dict == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open %s.\n", dictionary);
        return 1;
    }

    // create root 
    root = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node)); 

    // initialize all pointers in root to NULL
    for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++)
    {
        root->letters[i] = NULL;
    }

    // initialize trav
    node* trav = root; 
    // initialize temp variable to store new word
    int letter;

    // while loop to read through the dictionary 
    while ((letter = fgetc(dict)) != EOF)
    {
        build_trie(letter, trav, dict);    
    }

    if (letter == EOF)
        return true;
    else 
        return false;
}

// build a trie function 
// to be used within load function recursively 

int build_trie(int letter, node* trav, FILE* dict)
{
    // set up place as value of letter - letters array place to "open"
    int place = letter;


    // set base case for recursive function -> end of string  "\n"
    if (letter == '\n')
    {
        trav->is_word = true; 
        total_words++;
        for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++)
        {
            trav->letters[i] = NULL;
        }
        return 0; 
    }

    // recursive part 
    else
    {
        // determine where in letters arrays to go 
        if (isalpha(letter))        
        {
            place = letter - 97;         
        }
        else if (letter == 44)
        {
            place = 26;    
        }

        // check to see if new node exists
        // if not - create new node and recurse with new letter and pointer 
        if (trav->letters[place] == NULL)
        {
            trav->letters[place] = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));

            // initialize new nodes pointers to NULL
            for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++)
            {
                trav->letters[place]->letters[i] = NULL;
            }

            letter = fgetc(dict);
            return(build_trie(letter, trav->letters[place], dict));
        }

        // if it does exist - get new letter - and recurse with pointer to that node 
        else
        {
            letter = fgetc(dict);
            return build_trie(letter, trav->letters[place], dict);
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

/**
 * Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded else 0 if not yet loaded.
 */
unsigned int size(void)
{
    return total_words;
}

/**
 * Unloads dictionary from memory.  Returns true if successful else false.
 */
bool unload(void)
{
    node* head = root;
    return unloader(head);
}

/**
 * recursive function to free the trie takes in the "head" of the trie
 */
// use recursion to free all nodes 
bool unloader(node* head)
{    
    // check base case - all null pointers -> free 
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++)
    {
        if (head->letters[i] == NULL)
        {
            total++;
        }
    }

    // base case all 27 pointers == NULL
    if (total == 27)
    {
        free(head);
        head = NULL;
        return true; 
    }
    else 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++)
        {
            if (head->letters[i] != NULL)
            {
                unloader(head->letters[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The source code doesn't compile, the main() function and the node are missing. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: this is the node declaration from the .h file:                                              typedef struct node,
{        
    bool is_word;
    struct node* letters[27];
}
node;

Comment: Could you confirm that the error occurs during the loading of the dictionary ? If so, the `DICTIONARY` file is certainly damaged.

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -g`) then use a debugger (`gdb`) & [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When looking at your code, there is an incoherence between the `build_trie()` during the dictionary load and the `check()` function to search a read word in the dictionary.

In the `build_trie()` function, the `letters[26]` is used to the ASCII code 44 (magic number ?):

```
if (isalpha(letter))
{
    place = letter - 97;
}
else if (letter == 44) // magic number = ','
{
    place = 26;
}
```

In the `check()` function, the `letters[26]` is used to `'`(apostrophe).

```
else if (word[i] == '\'') // apostrophe character = ASCII 39
{
    if (trav->letters[26] == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        trav = trav->letters[26];
        i++;
    }
}
```

In the `build_trie()` function, when the `place` index is calculated, there are the following unexpected behavior:

```
if (isalpha(letter)) // both uppercase/lowercase are available 
{
    place = letter - 97; // magic number 97 = ASCII 'a'
}
else if (letter == 44) //'\'')
{
    place = 26;
}

if (trav->letters[place] == NULL)
```

> Using the magic number 97 instead of 'a', could occur a negative
>   `place` index if `letter` is an uppercase. And before accessing to the
>   `letters[place]`, the index is not checked.
>
> If the `letter` is not isalpha() nor 44 and nor `\n`, the `place`
>   index has been assign to the `letter` value and could be any 8bits
>   value.

Before using a potential negative `place` index, you can add that exit code.

```
if ((place < 0) || (place > 26)) {
    //  exit when unexpected letter is loaded
    printf("Unexepected \"%c\"(%d) in dictionary.\n",(char)letter,letter);
    return (-1);
}

if (trav->letters[place] == NULL)
```

In the `unloader()`function, the return condition is not depending on the recursive return conditions and is only `true` for a leave-node (with `is_word = true`). An alternate function could be:

```
bool unloader(node* head)
{
    // only return false when node hasn't allocated 
    if (head == NULL) return (false);        

    bool bRes = true; // default answer is true

    for(int i=0;i<27;i++)
    {
        // only call the recursive unloader() when allocated
        if (head->letters[i]!=NULL) {
            // check if all allocated node are freed
            bRes = (bRes && unloader(head->letters[i]));
        }
    }
    // free the leave-node
    free(head);
    head = NULL;
    return (bRes);
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!!! I changed all the values to sync up and used 'a' and '/'' uniformly. There is still a problem unloading the dictionaries. Any thoughts?

Comment: Yes, I detect the issue on the `unload()`... Looking for a solution in progres.

Comment: @lyric updated answer with `unload()` alternate solution.

Comment: This works a lot better than the fix i made. There is 1 still reachable leak though. Can you explain how the head ==null return false line works. Is it a faster to way to see if all 27 pointers point to NULL?

Comment: The line `if (head == NULL) return (false);` is normally never used, it is just to protect the access to `head->letters[i]` and be sure that the `free(head);` could be call. The line `head = NULL;` is not needed because the parameter `node* head` is not sent by reference.

Comment: Thank you! This is great. I really appreciate the help

Comment: Have you really detected 1 memory leak ? I have added one counter of `malloc()` and one of `free()` and no difference before exit from the program.

Comment: Yeah I can't figure out why. I also tinkered with my other solution to the unload function  And now both of them perform identically. There is 1 still reachable block of 568 bytes in both versions of the solution. 367,084 allocations and 367,083 frees...